# -Directory switch not always working in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Butchering a Powershell script together and I seem to be getting inconsistent behaviour with the -Directory switch for dir (Get-ChildItem cmdlet).

If I run a regular Powershell instance and enter `dir -Directory`, it works fine.

However, when I put this in a .ps1 file and run it, I get this:

`Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'.`

What gives?

I'm on Windows 10 with Powershell 5.1

Comment: More info:  The full command is this (in my script):  `$var = dir -Directory`, I'm expecting the `dir -Directory` resuts to be put in `$var`, but is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: PLEASE put all the info  in your _Original Post_. [*grin*]

Comment: you seem to have somehow started PS2.0 since the `-Directory` parameter was added in v3. try adding `$Host` to the beginning of your script. i cannot recall if `$PSVersionTable` exists in ps2.0, but i know that `$Hosts` will be there. [*grin*]

Comment: Wow, Lee. I couldn't reproduce, but you're right: `powershell -Version 2 -Command Get-ChildItem -Directory` shows the exact error.

Comment: Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 5.1.17763.592
InstanceId       : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-AU
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions
DebuggerEnabled  : True
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace

Comment: @Yabbie - when you want to reply to a comment, you need to start it with `@` and the username - which should auto-fill.

Comment: @Yabbie - your `$Host` info indicates you ran the script in the ISE. your question seems to indicate that you ran it some other way - likely in the `powershell.exe` console. ///// so, how are you running the script when it gives you an error with that parameter?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey it seems to be inconsistent (which I'm sure it's not).  I've found a work around, but using `Get-ChildItem -Attributes Directory`

Comment: @Yabbie - i'm glad to know that you got it working as needed. [*grin*] however, you likely should spend a good deal of effort to identify the source of the problem so that you can fix it - or at least gracefully detect & deal with it. otherwise it will almost certainly give you other odd problems ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 5):

This can happen if you run PowerShell v2.0, or PowerShell in version 2 mode, or `SQLPS.exe`, but usually this happens because the provider of the current context does not support the `-Directory` parameter.

For example, this works fine:

```
Set-Location C:\
Get-ChildItem -Directory C:\
```

This will error:

```
Set-Location HKLM:\
Get-ChildItem -Directory C:\
```

Because the Registry provider uses a somewhat different version of the command.

This also fails:

```
Set-Location Function:\
Get-ChildItem -Directory
```

Because the function provider is so different that it doesn't even know what a container is.

See [`Get-Help about_Providers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bacon Bits.  I'm using version 5.1.